# How to connect from a +/- 15v audio circuit to single powered amplifier

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, input

I built a 3 WAY CROSSOVER (ELLIOT SOUND CIRCUIT) with +/- 15v supply. I have found small class D amplifier for Mid AND high amplifiers. They are single sided power. Can I simply couple the input through a capacitor and ground? Will signal cause problem when it crosses zero to negative value? the voltages are supplied from a transformer with +/- 38 v and +/-15v bridge rectified and capacitors. Grounds tied together. If a coupling capacitor is the answer, what value would allow suitable hi pass for audio? thanks[image: crossover output section and power]
[image: single powered amplifier board]
output section of crossover mid and hi shown. Low Frequency goes to an amplifier that is dual supply +/- 38vdc
the amplifier board shown is similar to one in my question, same wiring inputs
Thanks

Comment: Provide a schematic or diagram, please. Also, a link to the crossover you've built would be helpful.

Comment: There is no generic power amp circuit - supply a schematic.

Comment: Here is the crossover output section and power supply +/-15v

Comment: This is a project to build a 3 way powered speaker. original test had mid and low amplifiers that use +/- power supply. Wanted to try other amplifier board that has a single supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, a coupling capacitor in-line between the crossover's output & the amplifier's input will "re-center" the signal to the "artificial ground" inside the single-sided amplifier & avoid having problems when the 2-sided input "crosses ground."
2. The size of capacitor you should use depends on the input impedance of your amplifier. I'd say a cap with <1/2 the input impedance of the amplifier, at the lowest frequency you intend to push through it (i.e. 310hz for mid, and 3.1khz for high) should be sufficient. However, it's a lot harder to "mess up" by using too large a capacitor than by using one that's too small, so when in doubt, use a slightly larger cap.

Here's a link to a "Capacitive Reactance Calculator" ... tell it what frequency & impedance (reactance) you need, and it'll tell you the value of capacitor to get it; then go to your favorite component supplier & buy the next higher value that they have in stock (no need to pay $75 for a 10.2876358uF capacitor if a 11uF is handy for $0.15).

NOTE: DO NOT USE AN ELECTROLYTIC CAPACITOR FOR THIS...make SURE you use a "non-polar" capacitor. Mica, oil-and-paper, film, thin film, or ceramic are all fine...aluminum & tantalum capacitors aren't fine...the polarized/electrolytics can end up depolarizing & cause very unpleasant things to happen when used as coupling capacitors without adding a DC bias to keep them properly polarized at all times.